# Generic constraints, where T : struct and where T : class

Tags: c#, generics, class, struct, constraints

I would like to differentiate between following cases:

1. A plain value type (e.g. `int`)
2. A nullable value type (e.g. `int?`)
3. A reference type (e.g. `string`) - optionally, I would not care if this mapped to (1) or (2) above

I have come up with the following code, which works fine for cases (1) and (2):

```
static void Foo<T>(T a) where T : struct { } // 1

static void Foo<T>(T? a) where T : struct { } // 2
```

However, if I try to detect case (3) like this, it does not compile:

```
static void Foo<T>(T a) where T : class { } // 3
```

The error message is *Type 'X' already defines a member called 'Foo' with the same parameter types*. Well, somehow I cannot make a difference between `where T : struct` and `where T : class`.

If I remove the third function (3), the following code does not compile either:

```
int x = 1;
int? y = 2;
string z = "a";

Foo (x); // OK, calls (1)
Foo (y); // OK, calls (2)
Foo (z); // error: the type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type ...
```

How can I get `Foo(z)` to compile, mapping it to one of the above functions (or a third one with another constraint, which I have not thought of)?

Comment: For reference types there is : new(), however this has odd behaviour with nullable value types.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Constraints are not part of the signature, but parameters are. And constraints in parameters are enforced during overload resolution.

So let's put the constraint in a parameter. It's ugly, but it works.

```
class RequireStruct<T> where T : struct { }
class RequireClass<T> where T : class { }

static void Foo<T>(T a, RequireStruct<T> ignore = null) where T : struct { } // 1
static void Foo<T>(T? a) where T : struct { } // 2
static void Foo<T>(T a, RequireClass<T> ignore = null) where T : class { } // 3
```

(better six years late than never?)

Comment: Ha, great idea! In fact, you do not need to add the `ignore` parameter to the second `Foo<T>` function taking `T?`.

Comment: This gave me the opportunity to blog about the topic on http://code.fitness/post/2016/04/generic-type-resolution.html

Comment: I got the idea from [one of Eric Lippert's blog posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/). I've always liked shenanigans. As for the T?, the situation in which I needed this only had cases 1 and 3, and I forgot testing if it's needed.

Comment: This is slick as snot. I like using "_" instead of "ignore" a la functional programming.

Comment: Simpler way, without the need for helper classes: Not sure if this is newer language version only or whatever. I guess it may cause an extra allocation of the struct, but I needed to test for equality to default anyway.

`static void Foo<T>(T? value) where T : struct { }`
    
`static void Foo<T>(T value, T defaultValue = default) where T : struct { }`
    
`static void Foo<T>(T obj) where T : class { }`

Answer (score 23):

You cannot differentiate the type of method to call based only on the constraints, unfortunately.

So you need to define a method in a different class or with a different name instead.

Comment: +1.  Of course, the first and second work because `T` and `T?` are different arguments. (`T` and `Nullable<T>`)

Comment: +1 See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply; if I cannot differentiate the types, is there some way to get my last example to compile, by relaxing some constraint?

Comment: Ah, simply drop the `where T : struct` for method (1) and my example compiles. That's enough for me.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to differentiate the type of a method call based upon constraints if one doesn't mind having a dummy "optional" parameter of a generic reference type which has constraints on its generic arguments, and having a "null" default value for that parameter.  Since the compiler will exclude from consideration any overload whose type cannot be constructed, the constraints in the type of the dummy parameter will be effective in limiting what overloads are considered.  Of course, if a compiler can do that at a call site which doesn't give a value for a dummy argument, it...

Comment: ...should be just as capable of doing so without requiring the caller to pass a dummy argument, but I don't know any way to achieve that.

Answer (score 10):

Further to your comment on [Marnix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974519/generic-constraints-where-t-struct-and-where-t-class/2974742#2974742), you can achieve what you want by using a bit of reflection.

In the example below, the unconstrained `Foo<T>` method uses reflection to farm out calls to the appropriate constrained method - either `FooWithStruct<T>` or `FooWithClass<T>`. For performance reasons we'll create and cache a strongly-typed delegate rather than using plain reflection every time the `Foo<T>` method is called.

```
int x = 42;
MyClass.Foo(x);    // displays "Non-Nullable Struct"

int? y = 123;
MyClass.Foo(y);    // displays "Nullable Struct"

string z = "Test";
MyClass.Foo(z);    // displays "Class"

// ...

public static class MyClass
{
    public static void Foo<T>(T? a) where T : struct
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nullable Struct");
    }

    public static void Foo<T>(T a)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);

        Delegate action;
        if (!FooDelegateCache.TryGetValue(t, out action))
        {
            MethodInfo mi = t.IsValueType ? FooWithStructInfo : FooWithClassInfo;
            action = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>), mi.MakeGenericMethod(t));
            FooDelegateCache.Add(t, action);
        }
        ((Action<T>)action)(a);
    }

    private static void FooWithStruct<T>(T a) where T : struct
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Non-Nullable Struct");
    }

    private static void FooWithClass<T>(T a) where T : class
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class");
    }

    private static readonly MethodInfo FooWithStructInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("FooWithStruct", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    private static readonly MethodInfo FooWithClassInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("FooWithClass", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> FooDelegateCache = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();
}
```

(Note that *this example is not threadsafe*. If you require thread-safety then you'll either need to use some sort of locking around all access to the cache dictionary, or -- if you're able to target .NET4 -- use [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) instead.)

Comment: Could one improve things by using an approach similar to `Comparer<T>.Default`, e.g. create a private static generic class `FooInvoker<T>` with a public field `FooMethod` of type `Action<T>` (since `FooInvoker<T>` would be inaccessible outside `MyClass` there would be no risk of outside code abusing the public field)?  If class constructor for `FooInvoker<T>` sets `FooMethod` appropriately, I think that would might avoid the need for a dictionary look-up at runtime (I don't know whether .net would need to perform one internally every time `Foo<T>` was called).

Comment: See my posted answer for an outline of how one would use a static class.  I probably made some syntax errors, since I'm typing from memory (and mostly program in vb.net), but there should be enough of an outline to get you going.

Answer (score 5):

Drop the struct contraint on the first method. If you need to differentiate between value types and classes you can use the type of the argument to do so.

```
      static void Foo( T? a ) where T : struct
      {
         // nullable stuff here
      }

      static void Foo( T a )
      {
         if( a is ValueType )
         {
            // ValueType stuff here
         }
         else
         {
            // class stuff
         }
      }
```

Comment: @Maxim: Thank you. The problem I am facing is that in the non nullable method, I have to be able to invoke other functions which take and return `T?`, and this is not valid without the `where T : struct` constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Amplifying my comment to LukeH, a useful pattern if one will need to use Reflection to invoke different actions based upon a type parameter (as distinct from the type of an object instance) is to create a private generic static class something like the following (this exact code is untested, but I've done this sort of thing before):

```
static class FooInvoker<T>
{
  public Action<Foo> theAction = configureAction;
  void ActionForOneKindOfThing<TT>(TT param) where TT:thatKindOfThing,T
  {
    ...
  }
  void ActionForAnotherKindOfThing<TT>(TT param) where TT:thatOtherKindOfThing,T
  {
    ...
  }
  void configureAction(T param)
  {
    ... Determine which kind of thing T is, and set `theAction` to one of the
    ... above methods.  Then end with ...
    theAction(param);
  }
}
```

Note that Reflection will throw an exception if one attempts to create a delegate for `ActionForOneKindOfThing<TT>(TT param)` when `TT` does not comply with that method's constraints.  Because the system validated the type of `TT` when the delegate was created, one can safely invoke `theAction` without further type-checking.  Note also that if outside code does:

```
  FooInvoker<T>.theAction(param);
```

only the first call will require any Reflection.  Subsequent calls will simply invoke the delegate directly.

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully this kind of messing around is required less from C# version 7.3

See [Whats new in C# 7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3) - Its not very explicit, but it now appears to use the 'where' arguments to some extent during overload resolution.

> Overload resolution now has fewer ambiguous cases

Also see [Selecting C# Version](https://dailydotnettips.com/choosing-the-c-language-latest-version-minor-release-in-visual-studio-2017/) in your visual studio project

It will still see clashes with the following

```
Foo(x);
...
static void Foo<T>(T a) where T : class { } // 3
static void Foo<T>(T a) where T : struct { } // 3
```

But will correctly resolve

```
Foo(x);
...
static void Foo<T>(T a, bool b = false) where T : class { } // 3
static void Foo<T>(T a) where T : struct { } // 3
```

Comment: I tried C# 7.3 and it does not change the collision between methods (1) and (3) in my original question. I still get error _Type 'X' already defines a member called 'Foo' with the same parameter types_.

Comment: @PierreArnaud Seems I jumped the gun a bit. My case was slightly different, and as that worked I assumed it would your case. I've amended the reply to reflect this....Seems MS have improved this but their is still some work to do...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need generic parameters and just want to differentiate between these 3 cases at compile time you can use following code.

```
static void Foo(object a) { } // reference type
static void Foo<T>(T? a) where T : struct { } // nullable
static void Foo(ValueType a) { } // valuetype
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest compilers the `RequireX` approach can be done without introducing extra types and using only nullable ones (see at the [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA2UgMQHs6BnAbjzwEsphSAPUgXlIFWuTsAD8pAJ4DS6ERTIAvWQCIAhqpF56dABQ8AlM1IB6U6QDyAaRikAxuoA2TxqT0FDOhnqnGzFjZ2ji5ueuheuLp6Sv7mVrYOzq7uAMyRGLQMjHgA3nikheSp5FTkACxZdAA8ACoAfHq1pOp2tZIA+rJQEC6GpADuABYApmAjpM0gpIzAkPbc/PWlAJwecRZEuEXFpdSolbp1je0t/cNjE1MzcxALAssUaxEm8egFRaglFPuHDMdNFptTrdXpOc6jcaTUjTTJLVZ6dKvCypPAAXyAA=)):

```cs
using System;
using static Foos;

int x = 1;
int? y = 2;
string z = "a";

Foo(x); // OK, calls (1)
Foo(y); // OK, calls (2)
Foo(z); // OK, calls (3)
class Foos
{
    public static void Foo<T>(T a, T? _ = null) where T : struct => Console.WriteLine(1); // 1
    public static void Foo<T>(T? a) where T : struct => Console.WriteLine(2); // 2
    public static void Foo<T>(T a, T? _ = null) where T : class => Console.WriteLine(3); // 3
}
```

Actually removing the 2nd parameter in the 3rd method also seems [to work](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA2UgMQHs6BnAbjzwEsphSAPUgXlIFWuTsAD8pAJ4DS6ERTIAvWQCIAhqpF56dABQ8AlM1IB6U6QDyAaRikAxuoA2TxqT0FDOhnqnGzFjZ2ji5ueuheuLp6Sv7mVrYOzq7uAMyRGLQMjHgA3nikheSp5FTkACxZdAA8ACoAfHq1pOp2tZIA+rJQEC6GpADuABYApmAjpM0gpIzAkPbc/PWlAJwecRZEuEXFpdSolbp1je0t/cNjE1MzcxALAssUaxEm8egFRaglFPuHDMdNM6DUbjSakaaZJarPTpV4WVJ4AC+QA=):

```cs
class Foos
{
    public static void Foo<T>(T a, T? _ = null) where T : struct => Console.WriteLine(1); // 1
    public static void Foo<T>(T? a) where T : struct => Console.WriteLine(2); // 2
    public static void Foo<T>(T a) where T : class => Console.WriteLine(3); // 3
}
```