# Generic contraints on method overloads

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I've got an interface with some generic methods, and I wanted to implement a method with overloads to either accept an instance of a class, or its PK value (which is either an int or GUID but does vary).

I added to methods similar to these examples:

```
    void DoSomething<TKey>(TKey key) where TKey: struct;
    void DoSomething<TModel>(TModel model) where TModel : class;
```

The 'DoSomething' method name on the second of these is highlighted, and the error is

> Type 'ISomeStuff' already defines a member called 'DoSomething' with
>   the same parameter types.

I'm surprised by this as I've clearly defined by parameters to be of different type: one is a class and the other a struct.

Why isn't this sufficient to make the signatures different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic constraints, where T : struct and where T : class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974519/generic-constraints-where-t-struct-and-where-t-class). See also Eric Lippert's article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

Comment: @Frederic: How did I miss that one!!!

Comment: Apparently the "Related" pane in the sidebar didn't pick it either, so it might be trickier than usual ;)

Comment: Ah right - I did scan the list of suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jon Skeet has an answer to everything: [click me](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/)

quote:

> the declarations only differ in generic constraints, and constraints
>   aren't part of the signature

Comment: Updated link, for future readers (Jon posted the same article on his personal blog, here): 
http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/

Answer (score 7):

Is possible to do it, you need create something like `enable_if` from C++

```
public class ClassTag<V> where V : class { }

public class StructTag<V> where V : struct { }

public void Func<V>(V v, ClassTag<V> dummy = null) where V : class
{
    Console.Writeln("class");
}

public void Func<V>(V v, StructTag<V> dummy = null) where V : struct
{
    Console.Writeln("struct");
}

public void Func<V>(V? v, StructTag<V> dummy = null) where V : struct
{
    Console.Writeln("struct?");
}

static void Main()
{
    Func("A");
    Func(5);
    Func((int?)5);
}
```

It can be expanded to use any disjoint `where` to distinguish between overloads.
Only drawback is that It cant be used inside another generic method:

```
public static void Z1<T>(T t) // where T : class
{
    Func(t); //error there
}

public static void Z2<T>(T t) where T : class
{
    Func(t); //ok 
}
```

**edit**
But there is possibility of use `dynamic` in that case to work around this limitation:

```
public static void Z1<T>(T t)
{
     Func((dynamic)t); //if `T == int` it will call "struct" version
}
```

Only drawback is run time cost similar to call to `Dictionary<,>` index.

Comment: I love this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If one wishes to invoke a member generically regardless of whether it has a class constraint or a struct constraint, and have it invoke a method with a suitable constraint, one may define an interface `IThingUser<T>` to act upon any type `T`, along with one a class which implements it for value types and another which implements it for class types.  Have a static class `ThingUsers<T>` with a static field `TheUser` of type `IThingUser<T>`, and have it populate that field with an instance of one of the above classes, and then `ThingUsers<T>.theUser` will be able to act upon any sort of `T`.

```
public static class GenTest93
{
    public interface IThingUser<T> { void ActOnThing(T it); }
    class StructUser<T> : IThingUser<T>, IThingUser<Nullable<T>> where T : struct
    {
        void IThingUser<T>.ActOnThing(T it) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Struct {0}", typeof(T)); }
        void IThingUser<Nullable<T>>.ActOnThing(T? it) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Struct? {0}", typeof(T)); }
    }
    class ClassUser<T> : IThingUser<T> where T : class
    {
        void IThingUser<T>.ActOnThing(T it) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Class {0}", typeof(T)); }
    }
    static class ThingUsers<T>
    {
        class DefaultUser : IThingUser<T>
        {
            public void ActOnThing(T it)
            {
                Type t = typeof(T);
                if (t.IsClass)
                    t = typeof(ClassUser<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
                else
                {
                    if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                        t = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    t = typeof(StructUser<>).MakeGenericType(t);
                }
                TheUser = (IThingUser<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                TheUser.ActOnThing(it);
            }
        }
        static IThingUser<T> TheUser = new DefaultUser();
        public static void ActOnThing(T it) {TheUser.ActOnThing(it);}
    }
    public static void ActOnThing<T>(T it) { ThingUsers<T>.ActOnThing(it); }
    public static void Test()
    {
        int? foo = 3;
        ActOnThing(foo);
        ActOnThing(5);
        ActOnThing("George");
    }
}
```

It's necessary to use Reflection to create an instance of `StructUser<T>` or `ClassUser<T>` if the compiler doesn't know that `T` satisfies the necessary constraint, but it's not too hard.  After the first time `ActOnThing<T>()` is used for a particular `T`, `ThingUsers<T>.TheUser will be set to an instance which can be used directly for any future calls to`ActOnThing(), so performance should be very good.

Note that if given a `Nullable<T>`, the method creates a `StructUser<T>` and casts it to `IThingUser<Nullable<T>>`, rather than trying to create a `sometype<Nullable<T>>`, since nullable types themselves don't satisfy any constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need generic parameters and just want to differentiate between these cases at compile time, you can use following code.

```
void Foo(object a) { } // reference type
void Foo<T>(T? a) where T : struct { } // nullable
void Foo(ValueType a) { } // value type
```