# Inability to overload generic methods with type constraints

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generic constraints, where T : struct and where T : class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974519/generic-constraints-where-t-struct-and-where-t-class)

Is there a particular reason that you cannot overload generic methods using mutually exclusive Type constraints in C#? For instance, take these methods:

```cs
T DoSomething<T>(T arg) where T : class
{ /* Do something */ }

T DoSomething<T>(T arg) where T : struct
{ /* Do something */ }
```

and try to invoke them with

```cs
DoSomething("1");
DoSomething(1);
```

The way I see it, the DoSomething() methods are mutually exclusive as far as the parameters that they will take - the first one takes a reference type, the second takes a value type. The compiler should be able to tell that the DoSomething call with a string argument goes to the first method and the DoSomething call with an int argument goes to the second method.

Am I missing something conceptually with generics here? Or is this just a feature that wasn't implemented in C#?

Comment: This duplicate text could be improved by adding a link to the duplicate answer. It's really frustrating if you can't find a solution and searching doesn't return any results, or way, way too many results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generic constraints are not part of the method signature

See this answer [Generic contraints on method overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764911/generic-contraints-on-method-overloads)

[Jon Skeet blog post on the topic](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints/)

Comment: The links provided in this answer are currently broken (as of 4/26/2015).

Comment: @bostIT Huh. I wonder what happened to Jon's blog. I'll see if I can find an updated link.

Comment: @bostIT Found the update and fixed the link

Comment: I personally believe that generic constriaints are stupid,  the clr should be able to figure out the semantics automatically based on T.