# How to pass an uninstantiated struct to object constructor in c#?

Tags: c#, struct, constructor

Is there a way to pass an anonymous struct to an object constructor in C#?

I am using the struct for deserializing JSON from within the new object.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass (List<object> NewObjects, ?anonymousStruct?)
    {
        NewObjects.Add (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< anonymousStruct > (JsonString));
    }
}
```

EDIT: To Clarify -> I wish to pass different kinds of structs into the class depending on what I need to deserialise, so I can't specify the struct ahead of time. The information is deserialised into the struct type and inserted into the list of objects.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This won't even compile.

Comment: I smell an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/232835)

Comment: @paqogomez generally this happens with anonymous types - you have generic method but can't pass type (since it is anonymous)... Sample in a post is indeed a bit awkward...

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but from the usage with a generic Deserializer it seems that [generic class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx) with type argument [restricted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to [`struct`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974519/generic-constraints-where-t-struct-and-where-t-class) may be exactly what you need:

```
public class MyClass<TStruct> 
      where TStruct : struct
{
    public MyClass (List<object> NewObjects)
    {
        NewObjects.Add (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TStruct>(JsonString));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think there may be some form of misunderstanding.  A struct is a value-type that you define.  As such, you can specify one as a parameter by declaring it as such (for a declared class constructor:)

```
public MyClass(MyStructType structVal)
{
    ...
}
```

Since a `struct` is a value-type, it will always be initialized.*  However, if you want to be able to pass a `null` reference to your constructor, just add a query right after the struct-type name:

```
public MyClass(MyStructType? structVal)
{
    ...
}
```

This means you can now instantiate your `MyClass` as such:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass(null);
```

The `structVal` parameter will be null and can be handled as such.  If your class absolutely needs a struct instance, you may need to create some way of defining a new `struct` as being in an uninitialized state.

[*] To be clear, a `struct` may contain reference type object that may be null (`string` objects, for instance) however, the reference to your `struct` will always be initialized once you define one in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`default(MyStruct)` is the construct you are looking for - [default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx).

```
var my = new MyClass (NewObjects, default(TemplateStruct));
```

Note that using generic method/class is better (as shown in other answers), but if your class must be non-generic than passing sentinel object is an option to pass type.